# Python: Problems with a list comprehension using module laspy

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

recently i understand the great advantage to use the list comprehension. I am working with several milion of points (x,y,z) stored in a special format *.las file. In python there are two way to work with this format:

```
Liblas module  [http://www.liblas.org/tutorial/python.html][1] (in a C++/Python)
laspy module [http://laspy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tut_part_1.html][2] (pure Python)
```

I had several problem with liblas and i wish to test laspy.

in liblas i can use list comprehension as:

```
from liblas import file as lasfile
f = lasfile.File(inFile,None,'r') # open LAS
points = [(p.x,p.y) for p in f] # read in list comprehension
```

in laspy i cannot figurate how do the same:

```
from laspy.file import File
f = file.File(inFile, mode='r')
f
<laspy.file.File object at 0x0000000013939080>
(f[0].X,f[0].Y)
(30839973, 696447860)
```

i tryed several combination as:

```
points = [(p.X,p.Y) for p in f]
```

but i get this message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Point instance has no attribute 'x'
```

I tryed in uppercase and NOT-uppercase because Python is case sensitive:

```
>>> [(p.x,p.y) for p in f]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Point instance has no attribute 'x'
>>> [(p.X,p.Y) for p in f]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Point instance has no attribute 'X'
```

this is in interactive prompt:

```
C:\Python27>python.exe
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from laspy.file import File
>>> inFile="C:\\04-las_clip_inside_area\\Ku_018_class.las"
>>> f = File(inFile, None, 'r')
>>> f
<laspy.file.File object at 0x00000000024D5E10>
>>> points = [(p.X,p.Y) for p in f]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Point instance has no attribute 'X'
>>>
```

the print p after the list is:

```
print dir(p) 
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'make_nice', 'pack', 'packer', 'reader', 'unpacked']
```

in a loop format i have always the same error

```
>>> for p in f:
...     print dir(p)
...     print p.X,p.Y
...     
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'make_nice', 'pack', 'packer', 'reader', 'unpacked']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 3, in <module>
AttributeError: Point instance has no attribute 'X'
```

using this code suggested by nneonneo

```
import numpy as np
for p in f:
...   points = np.array([f.X, f.Y]).T
```

i can store in an array

```
points
array([[ 30839973, 696447860],
       [ 30839937, 696447890],
       [ 30839842, 696447832],
       ..., 
       [ 30943795, 695999984],
       [ 30943695, 695999922],
       [ 30943960, 695999995]])
```

but miss the way to create a list comprehension

```
points = [np.array(p.X,p.Y).T for p in f]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Point instance has no attribute 'X'
```

thanks in advance for help.
Gianni

Comment: Could you try `print dir(p)` after your list comp?  This should show what's living inside a `Point` instance.

Comment: >>> print dir(p) 
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'make_nice', 'pack', 'packer', 'reader', 'unpacked']

Comment: That's strange. Could you please rewrite your code as a loop, just for testing. In each step dump p, dir(p) and type(p). Have you tested with different input files?

Comment: thanks. I done and i got always the same error

Answer (score 3):

Python is case-sensitive. Too me it looks like you ask for attribute `x`, but it should be an uppercase `X`.

Comment: Dear Achim. I tryed uppercase and not-uppercase

Comment: Gianni:  Try again at an interactive prompt.  Paste the entire code with the entire traceback into your question.

Comment: dear Steven, i posted in interactive prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import numpy as np
...
points = np.array([f.X, f.Y]).T
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `Point` has a `make_nice()` method that makes more attributes show up.

```
for p in f: p.make_nice()
```

Now your list comp should work (with uppercase X and Y--see comments below).

```
[(p.X,p.Y) for p in f]
```

note: This answer is not tested.  It is based on reading the source of [`laspy.util.Point`](http://laspy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/laspy/util.html).

Relevant source:

```
def make_nice(self):
    '''Turn a point instance with the bare essentials (an unpacked list of data)
    into a fully populated point. Add all the named attributes it possesses, 
    including binary fields.
    '''
    i = 0
    for dim in self.reader.point_format.specs: 
            self.__dict__[dim.name] = self.unpacked[i]
            i += 1

    # rest of method snipped
```

Comment: i have always the problem:
>>> for p in f: p.make_nice()
>>> points = [(p.x,p.y) for p in f]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Point instance has no attribute 'x'

Comment: @Gianni:  After running `for p in f: p.make_nice()`, what are the results of `print dir(p)`?

Comment: >>> print dir(p)
['X', 'Y', 'Z', '__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'classification', 'edge_flight_line', 'flag_byte', 'intensity', 'key_point', 'make_nice', 'num_returns', 'pack', 'packer', 'pt_src_id', 'raw_classification', 'reader', 'return_num', 'scan_angle_rank', 'scan_dir_flag', 'synthetic', 'unpacked', 'user_data', 'withheld']

Comment: >>> print p.X,p.Y
30943960 695999995

Comment: So there you have it:  `make_nice()` populated the dimension names in upper-case.  So your list comp should be `[(p.X,p.Y) for p in f]`.  Editing my answer to reflect this ...

Comment: i have always this message:
>>> [(p.X,p.Y) for p in f]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Point instance has no attribute 'X'

Comment: @Gianni:  Did you forget to do `for p in f: p.make_nice()` before trying your list comprehension?

Comment: Dear Steven. Yes I did.
>> for p in f: p.make_nice()
>> [(p.X,p.Y) for p in f]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17771/discussion-between-gianni-and-steven-rumbalski)